# Shaded Area of a Symmetrical Figure

Tags: geometry

[image]

I thought that because no dimensions are given, and because there do not seem to be any perfect squares (only rectangles), I chose K. However, the correct answer is G. Why is this so?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us use similar triangles, and sum their areas in different ways.
 Call $S$ the area of the shaded region, $W$ for the white one.
Call $T_1$ the area of $EFG$, and $T_2$ that of $FGH$. $W=2T_1 = 2T_2$, thus $T_1 = T_2$. And $S=2T_1+4T_2$. So $S/W = \frac{6T_1}{2T_1}$.

Another possibility: remark that the ratio is invariant if you apply an affinity centered on $A$. Compute it in a simple case where you know the lengths, for instance when $ABCD$ is a square.

Answer (score 1):

Let the length and breadth of the rectangle be $a$ and $b$

In the triangles BAF and CDF , the base and height are $ a/2  $ and $b$ respectively.

In triangles GAE and HED, the base and altitude are $a/2$ and $b/2$ respectively. The total shaded area will be $3ab/4$.
And unshaded area will be  shaded area from total area.

Answer (score 0):

## lazy hint:

1. Move $\triangle CHD$ to the left of $\triangle ABG$.
2. Move $\triangle BFG$ below $\triangle AGE$.
3. Move $\triangle FHC$ below $\triangle EHD$.
4. Count up your new rhombuses and decide what to do with all the time you saved not doing any algebra.